# broken paths in Arc 10.2 unable to save

Tags: python, path, save, broken-links

I am attempting to "replaceDataSource" with our new sde path. I am using v2.7 in Arc10.2. We have multiple direct connect path names and one service connect that has changed servers from using Oracle to Sql Server. My code works all the way through the print statements but then I get the error msg "unable to saveACopy, check my privileges". Please let me know if I'm on the right track with putting all of the various connect names into a list and then iterating through them the way I have written. Also, I have attempted every indent on mxd.saveACopy and del mxd but nothing after two weeks has seemed to work so I thought I'd finally ask for some geo geek wisdom!

```
Code:
```

> import arcpy, os, glob
>   arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\kmetivier\Documents\BrokenPaths\Folder5"
>
> for root, subFolders, files in >os.walk(r"C:\Users\kmetivier\Documents\BrokenPaths\Folder5"):
>
> > ```
> > for filename in files:
> >   fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
> >    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
> >    if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
> >        print "------------------------------"
> >        print filename
> >        #open the map document
> >        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
> >        #get all the layers
> >        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
> >            #get the source from the layer
> >            if lyr.supports("datasource"):
> >                pathList = ["Database Connections\PWDB.arvada.org.sde","Database >Connections\GIS - PWDB.sde","Database Connections\PROD - GIS.sde","Database Connections\DC >- PROD - GIS.sde","Database Connections\GIS to SDE1.sde"]
> >                print "%s -> %s" % (lyr, pathList[0])
> >                basename, extension = os.path.splitext (pathList[0])
> >                if extension.lower() == ".sde":
> >                    #NEW SOURCE
> >                    datapath = r"Database Connections\GEODATA - GIS.sde"
> >                    #overwrite the old path
> >                    lyr.replaceDataSource(datapath, "SDE_WORKSPACE", "")
> >                    print "replaced " + pathList[0] + " with " + datapath
> >                    print "---------finished " + filename
> >                mxd.saveACopy(filename +"_2")
> >            del mxd
> > ```
>
> ```
>         for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
>            if lyr.supports("SERVICEPROPERTIES"):
>                pathList1= r"(PWDB.arvada.org, 5151, {sde1}, {Database_authentication}, >{GDS}, {""}, {save_username_password}, {version}, {save_version_info}"
>                servProp = lyr.serviceProperties
>                print "Layer name:" + lyr.name
>                print "-----------------------------------------------------"
>                if lyr.serviceProperties["ServiceType"] != "SDE":
>                    print "Service Type: " + servProp.get('ServiceType', 'N/A')
>                    print "    URL:         " + servProp.get('URL', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Connection:  " + servProp.get('Connection', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Server:      " + servProp.get('Server', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Cache:       " + str(servProp.get('Cache', 'N/A'))
>                    print "    User Name:   " + servProp.get('UserName', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Password:    " + servProp.get('Password', 'N/A')
>                    print ""
>                    if extension.lower() == ".sde":
>                        #This is the NEW SOURCE that you want to point to
>                        datapath1 = r"Database Connections\GEODATA - GIS.sde"
>                        #replace the old path wih the new
>                        lyr.replaceDataSource(pathList1, "SDE_WORKSPACE", "")
>                        print "replaced " + pathList1 + " with " + datapath1
>                        print "finished " + filename
>                        mxd.saveACopy(filename +"_2")
>
>                else:
>                    print "Service Type: " + servProp.get('ServiceType', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Database:       " + servProp.get('Database', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Server:         " + servProp.get('Server', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Service:        " + servProp.get('Instance', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Version:        " + servProp.get('Version', 'N/A')
>                    print "    User name:      " + servProp.get('UserName', 'N/A')
>                    print "    Authentication: " + servProp.get('AuthenticationMode', >'N/A')
>                    print ""       
>              del mxd>>
> ```

Comment: This question is better suited for [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com), as you will find over there we are more familiar with the details of working with ArcPy, and determining whether the problem is with your code or with your mxds/ArcGIS in general.

Comment: Thanks. I got this working after all.